# How does the Bias Drive in TI ADS1299 help in noise reduction?

Tags: adc, bias, texas-instruments, biopotential, common-mode

I'm bit of a noob in electronics so please pardon me if this question is too basic.

I would like to clearly understand how the signal from the bias drive electrode can help in noise reduction, reducing baseline drift and other artifacts.

As a user puts it in [this](https://e2e.ti.com/support/data_converters/precision_data_converters/f/73/t/315426) forum page "This BIAS drive signal drives the patient with an inverted common-mode signal that can help reduce noise and 50/60Hz interference."

I'm not able to understand the above statement on how the inverted common-mode signal can help in noise reduction. If some can explain the intricacies behind this concept, that would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The body acts as an antenna for 50Hz or 60Hz radiation.  This can mess up low level signals and make it difficult to read out the ECG information.  A bias drive (also called Driven Right Leg) takes a copy of the 50Hz or 60Hz radiation and drives the leg with a scaled, inverted version, effectively canceling it out.  So, with a bias drive, the 50Hz or 60Hz interference appears both on signal and common, so you take the difference and it is canceled.